# C++ How to find out most consecutive digits in an array?

Tags: c++

Hi guys I'm trying to write a code where when i type a binary string I need to mind the most consecutive numbers of occurrence 1 has occurred. For example, if i type 00111001, it should be 3, 1100111011111, it should be 5 etc. This is my code so far.

```
int main () {


string s1;
cin >> s1;
int l1=s1.size()-1;  // length-1 hence the for loop array doesnt go out of bounds
int max=0;   // this tells us the max number of occurrence
int count=0;

for (int i=0;i<l1;i++) {


       if (s1[i]=='1' && s1[i+1]=='1') {  // if s[0] and s[1] are both 1, it adds 1
        count++;}


        if (count>0 && count>max)
            {max=count;  // storing the count value in max. 
             }

        if (s1[i]=='0' || s1[i+1]=='0'){  //resetting count if it encounters 0

        count=0;
    }
} 
max=max+1;


cout << max << '\n' << endl;
```

The issue is if I write 1111001 it runs (I get 4), but when i type 1100111001 I get 2. Don't get why there's ambiguity. Please let me know what I need to do
Thanks

Comment: Just count 1s and reset on 0s. No need to look ahead

Comment: Simpler solution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba85fc664c806900

Comment: Step through the algorithm one line at a time, using your debugger, examining the values of things. Compare what it's actually doing with what you wanted it to do. Fix the mistake you find.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce your problem](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c91b006066b7b6). Present a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the described problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd only increment the count in case of 1, and zero it when 0 is reached.
whenever count is bigger than max, assign count to max and that's it.
btw, I get 3 for the input 1100111001 with your program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    string s1;
    cin >> s1;
    int l1 = s1.size();
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++)
    {
        if (s1[i] == '1')
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
        }

        if (count > max)
        {
            max = count;
        }

    }

    cout << max << '\n' << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve this using [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), given `string s1` which contains your input string you can just do:

```
auto max = 0;

for(auto start = find(cbegin(s1), cend(s1), '1'); start != cend(s1); start = find(start, cend(s1), '1')) {
    const auto finish = find(start, cend(s1), '0');
    const auto count = distance(start, finish);

    if(count > max) {
        max = count;
    }
    start = finish;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/FYedr1)

Answer (score 0):

I want to offer you such an option for calculating through tokens and sorting:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1;
    cin>>s1;
    istringstream s(s1);
    vector<string> result;
    while (std::getline(s,s1,'0')) {
        result.push_back(s1);
    }
    sort(result.begin(),result.end(),[](const string &a, const string &b){ return a.length()>b.length();});
    cout << result.at(0).length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```